# Create Export in MEF (exportedValueGetter)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mef

Trying to list all Exports in my Catalog

```
var exportDefs =  ObjectBase.Container.Catalog.Parts.Select(p => p.ExportDefinitions);

        foreach (var item in exportDefs)
        {
            foreach (var e in item)
            {
                Export ex = new Export(e,???);
            }

        }
```

Not sure on how to implement Func ExportedValueGetter = second parameter in Export creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, trials and errors I got it

```
var exportDefs =  ObjectBase.Container.Catalog.Parts.Select(p => p.ExportDefinitions);

        foreach (var item in exportDefs)
        {
            foreach (var e in item)
            {
                Export ex = new Export(e,e.GetType);
                ObjectBase.Container.ReleaseExport(ex);
            }

        }
```

Having this is very important when using  Non-Shared creation, this code block releases all instances from container and frees memory.